# Where is search.php?

Tags: templates, search

I've got a site on Wordpress 4.0.1, and I can't find search.php.

A database batch process has applied a template to the default search results page, but I now can't find the page to change it back.

How can I change the template of this page?

Would creating a new "search.php" in my theme help? If so, what should this file contain?

Comment: yes it probably would, having `search.php` is not mandatory for a theme, if it is not present it will fall back to `index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, copying index.php file for the theme as search.php will let you have a new base template to work off of with the same styles and look as your theme, assuming the theme implemented index.php decently.

That would give you a solid start to be able to make changes to provided nothing is using a hook such as template_redirect to hijack the search results and use some other template to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Privateer was on the right track, however, copying index.php as search.php didn't change the results.

My solution was to find a known good copy of search.php and use that instead. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-paginate-cant-install-on was the copy. I've modified it for my purposes.